# Asymptotic solutions to generalized Airy equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am interested in asymtotic solutions, for $x \gg 0$ and $x \ll 0$ of the following differential equation:

$\frac{d^ny}{dx^n} + yx = 0$

Here $n$ is an integer $\ge 2$. 
For the particular case of $n=2$ the exact solution is known to be the Airy function (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function).

Comment: Have you tried it for the case $n=3$?

Comment: There are existed methods for finding these asymptotic solutions.

Comment: What methods might those be?

Comment: Check [method of dominant balance](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~gajjar/magicalbooks/methods/notest1_2se15.html).

Comment: Hmm, it is not clear how to apply that to my equation.

Comment: You need to practice the method!